# Backup H2DB Embedded?

Tags: java, h2

I have an application that I use H2DB and now I want to do backup of database.

Tried make a copy using FileUtils but does it return an exception that file database is locked because my application is opened.

I have a JButton to make backup

Tried use `BACKUP TO` like FAQ of H2DB and doesn't work also. http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#upgrade_backup_restore

I am trying this.

```
String bkp = "BACKUP TO /FerpaSistemas/MyApplication/backup.zip";
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
em.createNativeQuery(bkp).executeUpdate();
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:96)
at br.com.iguana.utils.BackupDB.backup(BackupDB.java:26)
at br.com.iguana.views.ViewPrincipal.jmi_backupActionPerformed(ViewPrincipal.java:652)
at br.com.iguana.views.ViewPrincipal.access$2900(ViewPrincipal.java:29)
at br.com.iguana.views.ViewPrincipal$30.actionPerformed(ViewPrincipal.java:459)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

14:49:25,306 DEBUG [net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker] - Checking for update...
14:49:25,723 INFO  [net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker] - New update(s) found: 2.4.7 [http://www.terracotta.org/confluence/display/release/Release+Notes+Ehcache+Core+2.4]. Please check http://ehcache.org for the latest version.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: What about releasing all database connections, performing the backup and then reopening the connection? Seems like a straightforward solution to me.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, you says to close connection, execute backup and after start connection again ?

Comment: Your backup query is a **native** query, so you should use `em.createNativeQuery(bkp).executeUpdate();`

Comment: @SvetlinZarev using `createNativeQuery` exception changed !

Comment: so we're making progress :-) what is the new exception?

Comment: @Leo I edited the post with new exception :)

Comment: try em.getTransaction().begin() before the command and em.getTransaction().commit() after

Comment: I tried but doesn't work

Comment: According to th exception, you have to execute the query inside active transaction.

Comment: You also need to quote the file name: `BACKUP TO '/FerpaSistemas/MyApplication/backup.zip'`